# Artifactory OSS with MariaDb

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, artifactory

Hope somebody can give me some hints.
Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 system, installed Artifactory OSS 7.12.6 using apt-get  (it ended up in /opt/jfrog/artifactory).
Then installed MariaDb and followed the instructions to link both (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/MariaDB).
Everything seems on the right place, Artifactory is happily running, I can store and retrieve artifacts, however Artifactory is not using at all MariaDB and continue to use Derby.
I can access MariaDb from console and did see no tables were created in the database.
Of course I can access the DB via the console using the credential assigned to Artifactory.
I did poke around in the Artifactory log files but I didn't see any error or any message related to MariaDb so I'm puzzled, how I can have Artifactory 7.12.6 OSS to use MariaDb ?
Maybe that version supports only Derby ?

This the system.yaml file :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-62:~$ cat /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/system.yaml
## @formatter:off
## JFROG ARTIFACTORY SYSTEM CONFIGURATION FILE
## HOW TO USE: comment-out any field and keep the correct yaml indentation by deleting only the leading '#' character.
configVersion: 1


## NOTE: JFROG_HOME is a place holder for the JFrog root directory containing the deployed product, the home directory for all JFrog products.
## Replace JFROG_HOME with the real path! For example, in RPM install, JFROG_HOME=/opt/jfrog

## NOTE: Sensitive information such as passwords and join key are encrypted on first read.
## NOTE: The provided commented key and value is the default.

## SHARED CONFIGURATIONS
## A shared section for keys across all services in this config
shared:
    ## Security Configuration
    security: 
    ## Join key value for joining the cluster (takes precedence over 'joinKeyFile')
    #joinKey: "<Your joinKey>"

    ## Join key file location
    #joinKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key>"

    ## Master key file location
    ## Generated by the product on first startup if not provided
    #masterKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key>"

    ## Maximum time to wait for key files (master.key and join.key)
    #bootstrapKeysReadTimeoutSecs: 120

    ## Node Settings
    node: 
    ## A unique id to identify this node.
    ## Default: auto generated at startup.
    #id: "art1"

    ## Default: auto resolved by startup script
    #ip:

    ## Sets this node as primary in HA installation
    #primary: true

    ## Sets this node as part of HA installation
    #haEnabled: true

    ## Database Configuration
    database: 
        type: mariadb
        driver: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/artdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8&elideSetAutoCommits=true&useSSL=false&useMysqlMetadata=true
        username: artifactory
        password: <*****>
    ## One of: mysql, oracle, mssql, postgresql, mariadb
    ## Default: Embedded derby
```

Thanks
STeve

Comment: Can you provide your system.yaml

Comment: I added it to the main post. Thanks

Comment: Does it any difference if you put quotation marks around the url?  url: "jdbc:..."

Comment: Not really. I probably will try to start from scratch again hoping to find some clues.
One thing that puzzle me is that when installed Artifactory the directory tomcat was not there (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat) and the JDB jar for MariaDb is supposedly to be put in such directory.
So I did manually created and copied the JDB .. maybe this is the core of the problem.
Did assigned the ownership to artifactory:artifactory, maybe should be something different ?
Or I need to install tomcat ?

Comment: Ok, the problem seems related to the MariaDB JBDC connector (https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/). I did download the latest one as suggested and put in the /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/bootstrap/artifactory/tomcat/lib directory.
I did copied it again (mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar) and now the website is down, probably because It can't access the db. 
The artifactory server is running, no errors.
I forced the permissions as artifactory:artifactory and made it executable.
Should have some particular permission ?